# My kitchen faucet was installed so that the water doesn't flow into the center of the sink

Tags: kitchens, faucet

[image]

The water does not flow into the center of the sink. It hits into the sink about 3/4 back. Lots of water gets splashed up on the counter behind the sink.

Can I bend the faucet so that the nozzle is aimed at the center of the sink? I'm thinking I would wrap the faucet with cloth and get a wrench and bend it about 1/2 inch out or heat it up and then bend it out a bit.
What do you think?

Comment: Looks like the holes for your faucet assembly were drilled into the counter too far back from the opening for the sink for your facucet.  If the location of the flow really bothers you, I would look for a faucet with a bigger goose neck (the curved part).

Comment: Consider that as-pictured you have quite a good access level to your sink, without the nozzle being in your way.  If the tab was further forward it might impede your access.  The aerator answer definitely looks promising.

Comment: Thank you all so much for responding. I am going to look into the aerator. The sink is polished nickel and I’m hoping to find an aerator in that finish.

Comment: They have sink splash guards that you can put in the bottom of the sink to prevent splash up, perhaps this could work?

Comment: When does the splashing happen? Is it when you're filling the sink, or when you're washing something under the running water? Or something else?

Comment: I feel like *most* sink faucets do not hit the center of the sink, and are further back by design.  I wouldn't fault the installer for this, as it seems like that's by far the most common scenario for a kitchen (or bathroom) sink.

Comment: The way to stop a tap splashing is not to point it at the flat base of the sink, but down the side, so the rounded turn into the bottom gently dissipates the energy. Pointing the flow towards the centre, without adding an aerator, would just soak *you* rather than the backsplash.

Answer (score 19):

Get an adjustable aerator that lets you point it where you want it. [An example from Amazon](https://amzn.to/3wX2ypf), but you can get at a local store too:

[image: swivel aerator]

Comment: Great solution - the only possibly downside would be if water splashes/bounces out over the front edge of the sink when its aimed forward.  However they're not expensive and totally worth trying.

Comment: @Criggie No worse than if you pull out the spray nozzle and aim it wrong.

Comment: Be aware that this particular tap requires a single hole in the sink counter, whereas the sink counter from OP's original picture clearly has two tap holes.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem the picture and link is not to replace the faucet, just the aerator.

Comment: OK, makes sense.  I'm thinking it might be difficult to find an aerator that visually matches the existing tap, but I don't really know what's available in OP's area.

Answer (score 7):

Many faucets are cast metal and if you tied to to bend it that much, you'd just crack it off. You might be able to loosen the nuts that hold the faucet in place and move it forward. Heating it up will just ruin the finish. Another possibility would be to get a different aerator that reduces the flow. You can try to bend it a bit but do it very slowly and observe if it's actually bending or just moving and then going back to the original position. If it is bending, you can try it a bit more but be careful not to snap it off.

Comment: I doubt that there is such a thing, but if OP thinks a 1/2 inch difference would help, then something like a shim to raise the sink side of the faucet would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

That sort of tap won't bend well, and if it's heated up, will wreck the finish. It may be that the end has a thread to screw an adaptor to, as in the existing answers.

If not, the two options are - change the tap for one with a longer reach, or - change the tile (think it's a tile) behind the sink in order to replace that tap closer to the sink. But I reckon it still won't quite reach the centre...

Answer (score 1):

> Can I bend the faucet so that the nozzle is aimed at the center of the sink?

It looks like a chrome finish was applied to the fixture. Bending it **will** result in ruining the fixture.

You need either a new fixture which aims at the middle, has a detachable nozzle, or get a directional aerator.

Realistically, if the fixture extended to the middle then you'd always be fighting with it when washing dishes so it's better to figure out a directional solution.